# Launch Velocity for Simple 3D Projectile

Tags: mathematics, physics, projectile-physics

This is a pretty easy question, but I can't quite figure out the answer. I have:

1. The initial position of a projectile.
2. The gravity vector.
3. The (stationary) target I want to hit.
4. A maximum launch speed of the projectile.

I want to calculate the initial velocity the projectile must be launched at to hit the target, assuming it follows a ballistic trajectory.

Comment: My answer here (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54732/how-to-implement-deceleration-and-stopping-over-a-certain-distance/54808#54808) provides the kinematic equations for motion under constant acceleration. This is adequate whenever your projectile never rises too far above the Earth's surface, so that gravity can be assumed constant.

Comment: Thank you, but these are the forward equations (i.e given v_0 and g, where will it be at time t?). Further, they are in only one dimension. What I need is a re-arrangement of these equations to infer v_0 from a target and g.

Comment: Ah, I see, I just needed to do a bit of algebra and I found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to one of the comments:

```
Vector3 displacement = (end - start);
float dist = displacement.Length();
float T = dist / MaxSpeed;
Vector3 initial_velocity = 1.0f/T*(displacement) - 0.5f*Gravity*T;
```