# Undefined fireball movement behavior

Tags: c++, 2d, game-mechanics, movement, directx9

[image: bug]

[Demonstration video](http://youtu.be/UDcnYfhN8eg)

I try to do after the player shoot 10 times of fireball, then delete all the fireball objects and recreate a 10 new set of fireball objects. I did it but there is a weird bug happens that sometimes the fireball will come out from top and move to the right after shooting a few times. All the 10 fireballs should follow the player all the time and all the fireball should come out from player even after a new set of fireballs is recreated. Any ideas to fix it?

Variables

```
typedef struct gameObject{
float X;
float Y;
int length;
int height;
bool action;
};

// Fireball
#define FIREBALL_NUM 10
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 fireball = NULL;
RECT fireballRect;
gameObject *fireballDest = new gameObject[FIREBALL_NUM];
int iFireBallAnimation;
int fireballCount = 0;
```

Set up Fireball

```
void setUpFireBall()
{
    // Initialize destination rectangle, rectangle height and length
    for (int i = 0; i < FIREBALL_NUM; i++)
    {
        fireballDest[i].X = 0;
        fireballDest[i].Y = 0;

        fireballDest[i].length = fireballRect.right - fireballRect.left;
        fireballDest[i].height = fireballRect.bottom - fireballRect.top;
    }

    iFireBallAnimation = fireballRect.right - fireballRect.left;

    // Initialize boolean 
    for (int i = 0; i < FIREBALL_NUM; i++)
    {   
        fireballDest[i].action = false;
    }
}
```

Initialize fireball

```
void initFireball()
{
    hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(d3dDevice, "fireball.png", 512, 512,
    D3DX_DEFAULT, NULL, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
    D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0),
    NULL, NULL, &fireball);

    // Initialize source rectangle
    fireballRect.left = 0;
    fireballRect.top = 256;
    fireballRect.right = 64;
    fireballRect.bottom = 320;

    setUpFireBall();
}
```

Update fireball

```
void update()
{
    updateAnimation();
    updateAI();
    updatePhysics();
    updateGameState();
}


void updatePhysics()
{
    motion();
    collison();
}

void motion()
{
    playerMove();
    playerJump();
    playerGravity();
    shootFireball();
    fireballFollowPlayer();
}

void shootFireball()
{
    if (keyArr['Z'])
        fireballDest[fireballCount].action = true;

    if (fireballDest[fireballCount].action)
    {
        fireballDest[fireballCount].X += 10;
        if (fireballDest[fireballCount].X > 800)
            fireballCount++;
    }
}

void fireballFollowPlayer()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FIREBALL_NUM; i++)
    {
        if (fireballDest[i].action == false)
        {
            fireballDest[i].X = playerDest.X - 30;
            fireballDest[i].Y = playerDest.Y - 14;
        }
    }
}

void updateGameState()
{
    // When no more fireball left, rearm fireball
    if (fireballCount == FIREBALL_NUM)
    {
        delete[] fireballDest;
        fireballDest = new gameObject[10];
        fireballCount = 0;
        setUpFireBall();
    }
}
```

Render fireball

```
void renderFireball()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FIREBALL_NUM; i++)
    {
        if (fireballDest[i].action)
            sprite->Draw(fireball, &fireballRect, NULL, &D3DXVECTOR3(fireballDest[i].X, fireballDest[i].Y, 0), D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255, 255));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting fireballCount to 0 in updateGameState, so I think the problem is that what is being animated and drawn is fireballDest[0], which is the first of the new fireballs and was just initialised with a position of (0, 0), which, presumably, is the upper right corner.

Comment: Thanks. But why? Does the computer cannot update in time?

Comment: Thanks for accepting. No, the computer's doing what you tell it. But what are you trying to achieve? Why do you have a fireball-limit of 10, if you immediately replenish them anyway?

Comment: I want to shoot unlimited fireball and if a fireball hits enemy it will disappear immediately. I wonder if I just set all the 10 fireballs back to the player position to follow the player for replenishing after used up the 10 fireballs, will it hit the enemies during this process?

Comment: If you want the fireballs to follow the player, maybe you should try looking at steering behaviours: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44400/arrive-steering-behavior